# Oracle - Creating Matrix based on a single column

Tags: sql, matrix, plsql, oracle11g

I need to create a matrix based on the results of a column (name):

[image: Matrix Example]

As shown in the picture, the column can have repeated values and they will not be always the same. So the table creation would have to be dynamic.

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [cross join](http://www.sqlguides.com/sql_cross_join.php)

```
select 
    pair_1, pair_2
from 
    (select distinct name as pair_1 from TABLE_NAME),
    (select distinct name as pair_2 from TABLE_NAME)
where
    pair_1 <> pair_2
```